# Dealer (Server) to Dealer (Worker) Not Working

Tags: scala, zeromq

In the following `DEALER` to `DEALER` connection, the Worker `DEALER` sends `[][Foo!]`, i.e. a 2-frame message, to the Server `DEALER`.

```
package net.async

import org.zeromq.ZMQ
import org.zeromq.ZMQ.Socket

class Worker(name: String) extends Runnable {

  import DealerToDealer._

  val WorkerResponse = "Foo!".getBytes

  val id = name.getBytes

  override def run(): Unit = {
    val context = ZMQ.context(1)
    val worker = context.socket(ZMQ.DEALER)
    worker.setIdentity(id)
    worker.connect(s"tcp://localhost:$Port")
    runHelper(worker)
  }

  private def runHelper(worker: Socket): Unit = {
    println(s"Worker ${name}: sending Empty + ${show(WorkerResponse)}.")
    worker.send(Empty, ZMQ.SNDMORE)
    worker.send(WorkerResponse, 0)
    println(s"Worker ${name}: sent")
    val message = show(worker.recv(0))
    println(s"Worker ${show(worker.getIdentity)}: received message: $message.")
    runHelper(worker)
  }
}

object DealerToDealer {

  def show(xs: Array[Byte]): String =
    new String(xs)

  val Port = 5555

  val Empty = "".getBytes

  val WorkerMessage = "Bar!".getBytes
  val WorkLimit = 25

  def main(xs: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val context = ZMQ.context(1)
    val server = context.socket(ZMQ.DEALER)
    new Thread(new Worker("Bob")).run()
    server.bind(s"tcp://*:$Port")
    runHelper(server, 0)
  }

  private def runHelper(server: Socket, sent: Int): Unit = {
    if (sent > WorkLimit ) {
      println(s"SERVER: sent the '$WorkerMessage' message ${WorkLimit} times. shutting down.")
      sys.exit(0)
    }
    else {
      println(s"SERVER: sending Empty + ${show(WorkerMessage)}.")
      server.send(Empty, ZMQ.SNDMORE)
      server.send(WorkerMessage, 0)
      println(s"SERVER: sent")
      val message = server.recv(0)
      println(s"SERVER: received message: ${show(message)}.")
      runHelper(server, sent + 1)
    }
  }
}
```

However, when running it, only the print statements show the sending of the Worker's message. The actual receipt of the Server is not shown

```
[info] Running net.async.DealerToDealer
[info] Worker Bob: sending Empty + Foo!.
[info] Worker Bob: sent
```

Why doesn't the `Server` receive this message?

Also, is the `[][Message]` format correct for `DEALER` to `DEALER` communication?

Answer (score 1):

Yes the format of [][message] is correct, but remember you need to read (everything up to the) empty frame and then your message.

Comment: I start my worker on a new thread: `new Thread(new Worker("Bob")).run()`. How can I read everything up to the empty frame and my message? Simply do two `dealerServer.recv(0)`'s to receieve `[]`, and then `[message]`?

Comment: Oops, so you did. just receive frames in a while( ! empty ) loop, then read the message content after the while loop. Although as you get no debug out from the 'server' this may not be the problem